# Reasons to use a shallow copy instead of a reference in C++?

Tags: c++, shallow-copy

I'm curious in what circumstances would you actually create a shallow copy of an object instead of simply passing a reference to the object or making a deep copy of said object in C++?

My understanding is that if you have a read-only or immutable object, you'd simply want to use a reference. If you need to make changes to the copy without changing the original, or marshal some data to a different memory address space, you'd make a deep copy.

I can see using a shallow copy in the copy on write case (before you write to the object and finish off the deep copy), but are there some other reasons you'd want to use a shallow copy?

Edit: Trying to clarify the question.

Comment: In your example, I'm talking about passing a T& around, a reference (or possibly a pointer) to the root object.

Answer (score 2):

The two options on the table here (assuming C++11) are:

1. An object that has a shallow copy constructor/assignment operator.
2. An object that has is either expensive to copy or not copyable at all. Given C++11, it would have a shallow move constructor/assignment operator.

C++ is ultimately a value-oriented language. Until C++17, something as simple as this:

```
T t = someFuncReturningT();
```

would at least theoretically provoke a copy/move operation. C++17's guaranteed elision makes sure that this doesn't happen, but until then, that is considered to perform a copy/move into a `T`. Sure, pretty much every compiler will elide it. But it is still theoretically there.

However, with move operations, not having a shallow copy isn't such a bad thing.

The main reason why you would want shallow copy vs. expensive copy+shallow move is for types where copying is not merely a "shallow copy". `shared_ptr` for example. Copying isn't just copying a pointer or two; you also bump a reference count. Indeed, this is a result of the design of `shared_ptr` as a type: to allow multiple owners for an object.

And the only way to do that is if each of those owners have their own copy. Therefore, copying must be "shallow" in that regard.

So the advantage would be for cases where it's part of the object's design.

---

If you're talking about pre-C++11 days, shallow copy made more sense. Post-C++11, you can rely on inexpensive move operations, but pre-C++11, that's not available. So a shallow copy is pretty much the only way to reasonably return objects by value.

Comment: How does that address OP's understanding that "if you have a read-only or immutable object, you'd simply want to use a reference"?

Comment: @barakmanos: A reference to what? You can't use a naked `const char*`, since it doesn't have the behavior you want.

Comment: Well, I've assumed that OP is referring to structs or classes. Is the term *shallow-copy* valid for anything else besides that?

Comment: @barakmanos: Consider my example of a hypothetical `immutable_string`. Are we talking about passing around a reference to the string instead of copying `immutable_string` instances, or are we talking about passing references to `immutable_string` instead of copying it?

Comment: @NicolBolas A reference to your `immutable_string_t` object.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the following example:

```
shared_ptr<T> p1(new T);
...
shared_ptr<T> p2 = p1;
```

here p2 is a shallow copy of p1. You could have used reference here, but you could not if you return it:

```
shared_ptr<T> f() {
    shared_ptr<T> p1(new T);
    return p1;
}
```

Comment: That would be automatically moved from. In C++11, of course.

Comment: In second example but not the first.

Comment: Right, but the OP's point is still (potentially) valid: you don't strictly need shallow copying to be able to act on the object in reasonable ways.

Answer (score -2):

The first thing comes to my mind is moving a object.

Lets say you allocated a memory in class with new operator.

```
struct A 
{
    A ()
    {
        data = new int[50];
    }

    void destroy()
    {
       delete [] data;
    } 

   A ( const A& copy )
   {
       data = copy.data;
   }


    int* data 
}
```

Than lets say you want to copy this object. Why not just copying the pointer to the data instead copying all data.

```
A calculateA()
{
     A returnVal;
     for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
         returnVal.data[i] = i;
     return returnVal;
}
```

Shallow copy can be advantageous in this case.

```
A ( const A& copy )
{
   data = copy.data;
}

A newA =  calculateA(); 
// do stuff with newA
newA.destroy();
```

I am sure there will be thousand of other reasons as well.

To avoid double deletion when copying the copy can set to null.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

struct A 
{
    A ()
    {
        data = new int[50];
    }

    ~A ()
    {
        if ( data )
         delete [] data;
    }

    A ( A& copy )
    {
       data = copy.data;
       copy.data = nullptr;
    }

    int* data;
};


int main()
{
     A aVal;
     for ( int i = 0; i < 50; i++ )
         aVal.data[i] = i;

    A anotherVal = aVal;

    int i = 10;
    while (i--)
      std::cout << anotherVal.data[i]; 
}
```

Comment: Please explain the down vote so that I learn from my mistakes.

Comment: "*Shallow copy can be advantageous in this case.*" And you just explained how shallow copying can easily be *broken*. Because in your case here, you will attempt to delete the `data` array *twice*.

Comment: That is why I said "can be" because the question also asks "what can be the reasons" . It can be easily avoided with simple pointer checks.

Comment: `A ( A& copy )` That is not a copy constructor. Users have the right to expect that `A anotherVal = aVal;` will not modify `aVal`.

Comment: A user should also be able to expect that all object resources will be released when the destructor runs. Your last edit created a memory leak in the first example. Recommend a read of http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Comment: I am sorry but I can't see any leak. Can you tell me please. Does complete example(the second one) leaks or the first one. Do you mean in case when destroy won't be called?

Comment: `void func() {A a;}` would leak the buffer. You've broken RAII and violated the Law of Least Surprise by removing the destuctor and replacing it with the `destroy` function.

Comment: I my problem is the way I am looking into problem. Maybe I should change my perfective. From my point of view the OP is looking for the cases where shallow copy can be useful. Even it is not a complete example the focus here is shallow copy. The other problems can be solved by making the example bigger but I think it is not OP looking for.

Comment: @NicolBolas: Isn't `A(A& copy)` a copy constructor according to §12.8/3, which says: *"A non-template constructor for class `X` is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type `X&`, `const X&`,
`volatile X&` or `const volatile X&`, (...)"*?

Comment: P.S.: I'm not saying it's not a horrible idea to use a copy constructor with a non-const reference. But for better or worse, it's formally a copy constructor.